# Delete Drupal system blocks from the blocks listing page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there any way by which I could `delete` or at least `hide` the `drupal system blocks` from the `blocks listing` page as I have too many `blocks` in my site.I can't actually find the `delete` option for these `system blocks`.I would like to make the `block listing` page showing only those `blocks` that are related to my `custom theme`.Is there some method by which i could `delete or hide` these blocks rather than changing the `status` of these corresponding blocks in the `blocks table`.Hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Drupal, belongs to http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think may be we will get a speedy answer in drupal.stackexchange.com, But it doesn't mean we can't ask questions here. After all he added the tags man.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [block_admin_display_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.admin.inc/function/block_admin_display_form/6) for this in drupal 6.

Sample code:

```
// This will allow only blocks from block module.
// Place this code inside your template.php
function phptemplate_preprocess_block_admin_display_form(&$vars) {
  // List of modules which are allowed on the block page
  $show = array(
    'block',
  );
  // Scan through each disabled block entry and remove ones that aren't needed.
  foreach ($vars['block_listing']['-1'] as $key => $disabled) {
    $type = explode('_', $key);
    if (!in_array($type[0], $show)) {
      unset($vars['block_listing']['-1'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to delete them? Ideally, only administrators would be able to get to the configuration place to touch that list.

If you really had, to could implement this hook hook_block_list_alter in a custom module.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7

Comment: tanx for the reply @Kye.But i think hook_block_list_alter if for D7.